# Generate JSON output instead of key=value CSV

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, data-conversion

Python version 2.7.10

I have this script (which grabs AWS EBS volume meta data) which currently generates a `key=value` pair data which is CSV (comma separated value) output per line.

**Python script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Do `sudo pip install boto3` first
import boto3
import json

def generate(key, value):
    """
    Creates a nicely formatted Key(Value) item for output
    """
    return '{}={}'.format(key, value)
    #if isinstance(value,int):
    #    return '\"{}\": {}'.format(key, value)
    #else:
    #    return '\"{}\": \"{}\"'.format(key, value)

def main():
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name="us-west-2")
    volumes = ec2.volumes.all()

    for vol in volumes:
        if vol.state == "available":
            vol_state_num_value = 1
        else:
            vol_state_num_value = 0
        if vol.snapshot_id == "":
            vol_snapshot_id = "None"
        else:
            vol_snapshot_id = vol.snapshot_id

        output_parts = [
            # Volume level details
            generate('vol_id', vol.volume_id),
            generate('az', vol.availability_zone),
            generate('vol_type', vol.volume_type),
            generate('size', vol.size),
            generate('iops', vol.iops),
            generate('snapshot_id', vol_snapshot_id),
            generate('vol_state', vol_state_num_value),
        ]

        # only process when there are tags to process
        if vol.tags:
            for _ in vol.tags:
                # Get all of the tags
                output_parts.extend([
                    generate(_.get('Key'), _.get('Value')),
                ])

    # At last put volume state numberic value
    # i.e. 0 (in-use) and 1 (available/unattached) volume
        output_parts.extend([
            generate('state', vol_state_num_value),
        ])

        # output everything at once.
        print ','.join(output_parts)
        #print '{}{}{}'.format('{',output_parts,'}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Currently the output it generates looks like this**:

```
vol_id=vol-0abcdab1b68111f8b,az=us-west-2b,vol_type=gp2,size=5,iops=100,snapshot_id=snap-0abcdab1b68111f8b,vol_state=0,mirror=primary,autoscale=true,cluster=customer,Name=[customer-2b-app41] primary,role=app,hostname=customer-2b-app41-i-0abcdab1b68111f8b,state=0
vol_id=vol-0abcdab1b68111f8c,az=us-west-2b,vol_type=gp2,size=12,iops=100,snapshot_id=snap-0abcdab1b68111f9c,vol_state=0,state=0
```

I'm trying to convert the script so that instead of generating a `key=value` pair CSV row per line, it'll generate a JSON object.

I tried to tweak the script by using IF statement as shown in the script i.e. `isinstance()` for the value part (to wrap the value with double quote or ignore it if it's number and using the following line:

```
    #if isinstance(value,int):
    #    return '\"{}\": {}'.format(key, value)
    #else:
    #    return '\"{}\": \"{}\"'.format(key, value)
```

and

```
    #print '{}{}{}'.format('{',output_parts,'}')
```

But, that's not giving me the desired result.

Expecting the desired result as something like:

```
{
  {
    "vol_id": "vol-0abcdab1b68111f8b",
    "az": "us-west-2b",
    "vol_type": "gp2",
    "size": 5,
    "iops": 100,
    "snapshot_id":"snap-0abcdab1b68111f8b",
    ...,
    .....,
  },
  {
    "vol_id": "vol-0abcdab1b68111f8c",
    "az": "us-west-2b",
    "vol_type": "gp2",
    "size": 12,
    "iops": 100,
    "snapshot_id": "snap-0abcdab1b68111f9c",
    ...,
    .....
  }
}
```

I tried to use `json.dumps(output_parts)` but that didn't help to get the desired output. I don't need the CSV output.

Answer (score 1):

To convert your `csv` lines into a `dict` can be done with:

**Code:**

```
def my_csv_to_dict(csv_line):
    return dict(csv.split('=') for csv in csv_line.split(','))
```

**Test Code:**

To convert those dictionaries into json you can use the `json` lib.

```
test_data = [x.strip() for x in """
    vol_id=vol-0abcdab1b68111f8b,az=us-west-2b,vol_type=gp2,size=5,iops=100,snapshot_id=snap-0abcdab1b68111f8b,vol_state=0,mirror=primary,autoscale=true,cluster=customer,Name=[customer-2b-app41] primary,role=app,hostname=customer-2b-app41-i-0abcdab1b68111f8b,state=0
    vol_id=vol-0abcdab1b68111f8c,az=us-west-2b,vol_type=gp2,size=12,iops=100,snapshot_id=snap-0abcdab1b68111f9c,vol_state=0,state=0
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]

import json
print(json.dumps([my_csv_to_dict(x) for x in test_data], indent=2))
```

**Results:**

```
[
  {
    "az": "us-west-2b", 
    "autoscale": "true", 
    "Name": "[customer-2b-app41] primary", 
    "mirror": "primary", 
    "cluster": "customer", 
    "state": "0", 
    "iops": "100", 
    "role": "app", 
    "vol_type": "gp2", 
    "snapshot_id": "snap-0abcdab1b68111f8b", 
    "vol_id": "vol-0abcdab1b68111f8b", 
    "vol_state": "0", 
    "hostname": "customer-2b-app41-i-0abcdab1b68111f8b", 
    "size": "5"
  }, 
  {
    "az": "us-west-2b", 
    "state": "0", 
    "iops": "100", 
    "vol_type": "gp2", 
    "snapshot_id": "snap-0abcdab1b68111f9c", 
    "vol_id": "vol-0abcdab1b68111f8c", 
    "vol_state": "0", 
    "size": "12"
  }
]
```